# Tuleap-edit email notification content

Tags: tuleap

Where to edit the default mail notification content in tuleap. for eg) There is a field called "Name" which is visible(has permissions) to all users in tuleap but we need to remove the same field in mail notification content which hits the users at the time of Add/update happen in the task.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more precise on what you are trying to hide? Normally, you set appropriate permissions on fields you don't want to be seen by certain users and they will not appear in mails for them.